# Play Framework - play.data package not found

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

To much hope I turn to the awesome stackoverflow community, to pray that they may be able to help me with my problem.

So I am using a play framework. I am trying to receive a post request. Using java btw.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaForms

Thats the link im following.

This is my build.sbt:

```
name := """DankBank"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  ws,
  // WebJars
  "org.webjars" % "webjars-play_2.11" % "2.3.0-3",
  "org.webjars" % "requirejs" % "2.1.17",
  "org.webjars" % "angularjs" % "1.3.15",
  "org.webjars" % "angular-material" % "0.9.0-rc3",
  "org.webjars" % "angular-ui-router" % "0.2.14"
)

//javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-Xlint:unchecked", "-encoding", "UTF-8")

//doc in Compile <<= target.map(_ / "none")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

And this is what I am in my import:

```
import play.data.*;
```

This is my error message:

```
error: package play.data does not exist

In C:\xampp\htdocs\uni\dankbank\app\controllers\Application.java:27
24import java.nio.file.Files;
25import java.util.List;
26
27import play.data.*;
28import forms.Login;
29
30import libraries.DankResponse;
31import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
```

I literally have no idea why the package is not being included.

Comment: What version of Play are you using in `plugins.sbt`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following in your build.sbt:-

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

to

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```